# Append items of a list to each line in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list of items that looks like:

```
White
Green
Blue
Yellow
Black
```

I'd like to append each item above to these lines of text:

```
Line One:
Line Two:
Line Three:
Line Four:
Line Five:
```

So that the final outcome is:

```
Line One: White
Line Two: Green
Line Three: Blue
Line Four: Yellow
Line Five: Black
```

My actual list is a couple hundred lines long. Is there a way to do this in Notepad++ with regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be faster to paste the columns into any old spreadsheet and then copy it back to a text editor.